# Bind2nd issue with user-defined class

Tags: c++, bind2nd

I'm trying to learn how to use bind2nd with user-defined classes, but I'm getting an error that I can't figure out how to fix despite my efforts of looking into other resources for assistance.

Help would be appreciated, thank you.

**main.cpp**

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>

class F
{
public:
  int operator()(int a, int b)
  {
    return a * b;
  }
};

int main(void)
{
  std::vector<int> bases;

  for(int i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
    bases.push_back(i);

  std::transform(bases.begin(), bases.end(), bases.begin(), std::bind2nd(F(), 2));
  // Error C2664: '_OutIt std::transform<std::_Vector_iterator<_Myvec>,std::_Vector_iterator<_Myvec>,
  // std::binder2nd<_Fn2>>(_InIt,_InIt,_OutIt,_Fn1)' : cannot convert parameter 4 from
  // 'std::binder2nd<_Fn2>' to 'std::binder2nd<_Fn2>'
}
```

Comment: Note that `std::bind2nd` is deprecated in C++11.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all you've to include *functional* to use the binder functionality.

Second you need to specify your operator() to be const.

Third, in order to get the type traits information, like *first_argument_type* and so on, it is best, in your case, to inherit from std::binary_function.

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
#include <functional>
#include <iterator>
#include <iostream>

struct F : public std::binary_function<int, int, int>
{
    int operator()(int a, int b) const
    {
        return a * b;
    }
};

int main(void)
{
    std::vector<int> bases;

    for(int i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
        bases.push_back(i);

    std::transform(bases.begin(), bases.end(), bases.begin(), std::bind2nd(F(), 2));

    // print it to stdout
    std::copy(bases.begin(), bases.end(), std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout, " "));
    std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

**Edit**

If you've access to a C++11 aware compiler and stdlib, your vector filling code can be easily rewritten to:

```
std::vector<int> bases(5);
int i = 0;

std::generate(bases.begin(), bases.end(), [&i]() { return ++i; });
```

With C++11 there is a new binder (moved from boost::bind) std::bind. This is far more flexible and you might give it a try, if you want to. Such as:

```
using namespace std::placeholders;
std::transform(std::begin(bases), std::end(bases), std::begin(bases), 
               std::bind(F(), 2, _1));
```

(I just have seen, from the answer below, that a.lasram mentioned the new std::bind. I don't know if you're allowed in your project, or whatever, to use new C++11, instead of old C++03 functionality. If I were you, I would, if you're not allowed, well then (to quote from famous Mr. Alexandrescu) "Call your agent." :) )

Btw. Ryan (see the comments) is absolutely right, when he mentions, that even my  most elaborate std::generate thing ;) can be shorter written using `iota`:

```
std::iota(bases.begin(), bases.end(), 1);
```

std::iota is defined in *numeric*. So you've to include that as well.

Hope that helps.

Comment: @Leif cheers sir! thank you for accepting it...please see my update for further information. you could even exchange your std.begin() to range based begin and end...

Comment: Actually, the vector filling code can be simplified even more by calling [`std::iota`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/iota), as in `std::iota(std::begin(bases), std::end(bases), 0)`.

Comment: @RyanMcK not the first time i've overseen iota...maybe because its short name ;)

Answer (score 2):

This completes Stefan's answer who pointed that `std::bind` takes a const reference as a functor argument and therefore `operator ()` has to be const.

Now, your binary functor must be adaptable to `std::bind2nd`.
`bind2nd` expects `F` to typedef `first_argument_type`, `second_argument_type` and `result_type`.

```
class F
{
public:
    typedef int first_argument_type;
    typedef int second_argument_type;
    typedef int result_type;

    int operator()(int a, int b) const
    {
        return a * b;
    }
};
```

C++11 introduces `std::bind` a more generic and flexible solution that does not have these required typedefs