# Cannot use std::ptr_fun with function that takes reference

Tags: c++

No C++11 or Boost allowed.

I am trying to get the following code to compile but I'm having problems. `std::ptr_fun` doesn't seem to like parameters that are references.

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <functional>
#include <vector>

struct Something
{
};

template<class T>
T Function(const T& x, int s)
{
    // blah blah
    return x;
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<Something> data(20);
    std::transform(data.begin(), data.end(), data.begin(), std::bind2nd(std::ptr_fun(Function<Something>), 8));
}
```

VS2013 error message:
error C2535: 'Something std::binder2nd>::operator ()(const Something &) const' : member function already defined or declared

But if I change the parameter in `Function` to `T x` it works!

Is there any way to get this working conveniently without modifying `Function`?

Live examples:

http://ideone.com/Eno7gF

http://ideone.com/kGmv7r

Comment: VS2013 supports a large portion of the C++11 library, so despite your restriction you do have access to `std::bind` and `std::placeholders`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot do this.  It is a fundamental limitation to std::bind1st and std::bind2nd.  The problem is that it defines two () operators, and one of them already has const & on it.  So the compiler sees two identical functions.  It won't be fixed since C++11 has already deprecated these methods.

See also:

[Using bind1st for a method that takes argument by reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7822652)

[weird compiler error using bind2nd(): "member function already defined or declared" instead of "reference to reference"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12349677)

[Bind2nd issue with user-defined class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17776601)